# Strange problem in using foreach in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I write below code in Ruby it gives me an error :

```
x = "c:/"
y = "Users/Amiref"
z = "/"
h = "Downloads"
v= x+y+z+h
Dir.foreach("v") do |i|
  puts i
end
```

but when I use below code Ruby doesn't give me any error :

```
Dir.foreach("c:/Users/Amiref/Downloads") do |i|
  puts i
end
```

I am really confused . please help me .
thanks

Comment: shouldn't that be Dir.foreach(v) instead of "v"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***v*** shouldn't be quoted - it's being used as a variable and not a string.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you quoted the `v`.

This means you are going through a directory called `v` which probably does not exist. :)

Remove the quotes and it will be the directory you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need `Dir.foreach(v)` without the quotes around `v`

Answer (score 1):

As already posted by the other answers: You may not quote 'v'.
Another hint: Instead building the path by hand, you could use File#join:

```
dir= File.join("c:", "Users", "Amiref", "Downloads")
Dir.foreach(dir) do |i|
  puts i
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
Dir.foreach("v") do |i|
  puts i
end
```

tries to loop through a "directory" called "v" (most likely \v or c:\v) and print all 
files and directories below that one.

What you really meant was probably

```
x = "c:/"
y = "Users/Amiref"
z = "/"
h = "Downloads"
v= x+y+z+h
Dir.foreach(v) do |i|
  puts i
end
```

**However**
I would recommend using File#join to join folders together, that way you become platform independent (somewhat anyhow) and don't have to fiddle with windows backslashes () and unix style slashes (/) like this:

```
dir_path = File.join("C:", "Users", "Amiret", "Downloads")
Dir.foreach(dirpath) do |dir|
  puts dir
end
```